# How to rewrite BASIC_FORMAT from logging python?

Tags: python, logging

Is it possible to overwrite BASIC_FORMAT from standard python logging module?

Comment: You mean literally overrite (so monkey patching) or use your custom format in your logging?

Comment: @kosciej16 Yes, i think about overwrite BASIC_FORMAT. Just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to patch that variable you need to do what we always do in such case. Find [where is it located](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5c4ca109af1c/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l1640) and replace it

```
import logging

logging.BASIC_FORMAT = "format"
```

IMPORTANT - it has to be on top of the imports, so we need to do patching before other files will import that file with old variable.

But I cannot guarantee you that it will work and how `logging` use that format under the hood. Better approach is to use parameter `format` passed to logging configuration:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    format="[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s",
)
logging.warn("message")
```